# How to implement negative infinity in python?

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I am trying to implement a Heap defined Priority Queue, the algorithm is from CLRS book chapter 6.
The pseudocode is listed below:

```
Max_Heap_Insert(A, key):
    A.heap_size = A.heap_size + 1
    A[A.heap_size] = -∞
    Heap_Increase_Key(A, A.heap_size, key)
```

My question is that using python, how do I define -∞?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Python has special values `float('inf')` and `float('-inf')`.

Comment: I prefer using the `inf` constant from the `math` module (`from math import inf`). You can then specify `-inf` for negative infinity.

Answer (score 6):

As it happens, in Python 2, `None` is less than any integer, so you can use `None`. In Python 3 you have (at least) four choices:

1. Use min(A) - 1.
2. Use `None`, and whenever you compare two values, explicitly test for them being `None`.
3. Define a new data type that consists of either an integer or -∞, and handles comparisons correctly.
4. Modify the algorithm so that line 2 is eliminated. You will have to patch `Heap-Increase-Key` somehow.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled across this while working on a heap implementation myself. :)

As of Python 3.5, you can use the inf constant from the math module

```
from math import inf
inf + inf                                        # inf
inf - inf                                        # nan
inf / inf                                        # nan
inf * inf                                        # inf
max(list(range(1_000_000)) + [inf])              # inf
min(list(range(-1_000_000, 1)) + [-inf])         # -inf
```

I did not know this and used a custom class to achieve the same ordering property

```
class MinusInf:      
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return False
    
    def __ge__(self):
        return False
    
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return True
    
    def __le__(self, other):
        return True
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return False


minus_inf = MinusInf()
minus_inf >= -1_000_000  # False
```

This will work for the purpose of a heap, but the recommended way is to just use `math.inf` (or `numpy.inf` which is the inf constant from numpy).

Answer (score 1):

Using the math library, you can do:

```
import math

a = -math.inf
```